# Why web controls does not have sufficient events like windows application?

Tags: asp.net

Hai , An asp panel contains only 6 events. if they provide a visibilechanged event it may very useful for me. if it is in windows application ,how easy it is.I dont know why thy are not providing all these.This is same as in the case of gridView, button ,etc.

just think , I have an Iframe in an asp panel and two buttons. In first time it is invisible .Buttons named first and second respectively. Two another pages One.aspx,two.aspx. These two pages contains each text box. When you click on the First button . I want to set the Iframe src="One.aspx" and display "first" in the textbox on One.aspx. as same in the case , when user clicks Second button. How to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Web technologies** work quite differently than **Desktop technologies**.

Desktop technologies can directly talk to native OS and hence they are functionally more rich.

In case of web technologies, the application runs on a web-browser which is independant of server-side web technolgy and vice-versa. Both the server and the web-browser talk using Http which is stateless transport service.

Some technolgies like **Flex**, **Silverlight** and **WPF browser applications** have gone beyond the browser limitations and they have become much more rich compared to traditional web-apps.

> **WPF browser apps and Silverlight are bridging this gap very fast.**

Answer (score 0):

Er, its quite hard to understand your disjointed sentences, but it sounds like you just want to handle the button clicked event.

In Visual Studio, in design view, double-click the button and it will generate the click handler event for you.